# Hive Query to get complete cases

Tags: hiveql

I have a table with 108 columns and most of the values contain NA and blank spaces. I want to get only rows where all columns are filled with values. If a column contains  NA or blank space, the entire row should be deleted. I know writing a UDF would do the job easier but is there a hive query for this. I would be glad to know about this.

Comment: By "deleted" you mean "skipped"?

Comment: Yes that row should not be selected